# Give all textfields a common property, for example roundedRect

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, rounded-corners

Is there a method to set all UITextFields in a ViewController to have a certain property, for example roundedRect?  Or should I do it like this ?

```
    creditCardNumberTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    monthTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    yearTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
    cvcTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
```

Comment: Are you creating Textfield from Interface builder or from coding?

Comment: than you can set it from interface builder itself no need of extra code, Attribute Inspector > Border Style > select the rounded one.

Comment: But then you can´t set the height

Comment: you can deal with height by using auto-layout constraints.

Comment: Ahh, ok, nice - Thanks.  That works. Shame they closed the question as duplicate

Comment: please have a look(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787162/style-all-uitextfields-at-once-rather-than-in-each-viewcontroller) as suggested by @rmaddy, if that doesn't answer your query please clarify further. Thanks :)

Comment: I did before I asked the question and I found them all quite elaborate, not in Swift and not very good.  Second the answers did not indicate that you can easily do it in the IB as you suggested. @shaf-khan